# ListView recycles item in wrong position when keyboard is hidden

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a really weird bug, that I cannot understand. Here is the behavior in video form http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHuUzNDI68w

Now to explain. I have an activity, called NewsFeed. which consists of a ListView of feed items (each has a photo that comes from a url, which I load using a caching class, and some text on the side) if I open this activity normaly, everything is alright, when I scroll around everything works as expected. If I however first press the search key, wherein the keyboard comes up, and I select something from the search results, the NewsFeed activity opens
At first when it shows up, the keyboard is still up, and then a split second later the keyboard goes down the end result is that the 2 images on top are identical (they shouldn't be)

Through some debugging I have figured out that for some reason the viewHolder for the top 2 rows, ends up being the same object on the second go round (once the keyboard is finally gone)

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final HashMap<String, Object> game = getItem(position);
        CollapsedNewsHolder collapsedNewsHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_collapsed_module, null);
            collapsedNewsHolder = new CollapsedNewsHolder();
            collapsedNewsHolder.newsPicture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NewsPicture);
            collapsedNewsHolder.progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Progress);
            collapsedNewsHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            collapsedNewsHolder.newsPerson = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.newsPerson);
            collapsedNewsHolder.upCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.upCount);
            collapsedNewsHolder.commentCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentCount);
            collapsedNewsHolder.relativeTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeTime);
            collapsedNewsHolder.setTypeface();

            //collapsedNewsHolder.imageCallback = new MyImageCallback(mActivity, collapsedNewsHolder.newsPicture, collapsedNewsHolder.progress, MyImageCallback.SMALL, 200);
            //collapsedNewsHolder.itemClickListener = new ItemClickListener();

            convertView.setTag(collapsedNewsHolder);
        } else
            collapsedNewsHolder = (CollapsedNewsHolder) convertView.getTag();

        if ((Integer) getItem(position).get("type") != NewsFeed.POSTER)
            collapsedNewsHolder.title.setTextSize(13f);

        collapsedNewsHolder.newsPicture.setImageBitmap(null);
        collapsedNewsHolder.progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageUtil.imageCache.loadAsync((String) game.get("img"), new MyImageCallback(mActivity, collapsedNewsHolder.newsPicture, collapsedNewsHolder.progress, MyImageCallback.SMALL, 200), mContext);

        collapsedNewsHolder.title.setText((String) game.get("title"));
        collapsedNewsHolder.newsPerson.setText((String)game.get("newsPerson"));

        collapsedNewsHolder.relativeTime.setText((String) game.get("relativeTime"));
        collapsedNewsHolder.upCount.setText((Integer) game.get("upCount") + "");
        collapsedNewsHolder.commentCount.setText((Integer) game.get("commentCount") + "");
        //convertView.setOnClickListener(collapsedNewsHolder.itemClickListener.set((String) game.get("id"), position));
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new ItemClickListener((String) game.get("id"), position));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Also here is an error log that illustrates the problem. Note the memory locations and the image urls, in regards to the position in the list.

```
05-05 17:34:54.774: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 0 Image- android.widget.ImageView@460977f8 Loading image- http://lh3.ggpht.com/o0vA6-MRGAXhhYYkPa1xf3WsPlDe4XnK2xWZeMhmXKBQI8eHGTAos0l1zqC_nox2MrRHKcCKNnPgzqLctsqh25e3LMc=s500

05-05 17:34:54.804: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 1 Image- android.widget.ImageView@46142f28 Loading image- http://lh6.ggpht.com/RcTe-3O-Rywdp0zizVx6k6lSEuPpYbDYnu1UoEnWbhLk6BzwzXt29BvK5rMPAqkrhgtvxvddSTL3pBnMDeLIXVV3s0EZng=s500

05-05 17:34:55.154: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 0 Image- android.widget.ImageView@46142f28 Loading image- http://lh3.ggpht.com/o0vA6-MRGAXhhYYkPa1xf3WsPlDe4XnK2xWZeMhmXKBQI8eHGTAos0l1zqC_nox2MrRHKcCKNnPgzqLctsqh25e3LMc=s500

05-05 17:34:55.174: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 1 Image- android.widget.ImageView@460977f8 Loading image- http://lh6.ggpht.com/RcTe-3O-Rywdp0zizVx6k6lSEuPpYbDYnu1UoEnWbhLk6BzwzXt29BvK5rMPAqkrhgtvxvddSTL3pBnMDeLIXVV3s0EZng=s500

05-05 17:34:55.304: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 2 Image- android.widget.ImageView@4615cd28 Loading image- http://lh4.ggpht.com/V95vJI4WHUUluC8_jHaJw011U6RO7I9rVBQsdSvwDrnUrOCN2YvqhHftr7o0YMNv8cIEBEjsnLNvIH0Y1KoB-rzw6hrKiQ=s500

05-05 17:34:55.334: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 3 Image- android.widget.ImageView@46061610 Loading image- http://lh3.ggpht.com/-c7Ss0t2luOD-npAFZcjRYbnuasqjUNTOv75pFhyprhyzGDf8QdIz_PrJS5qcmBb0a5xrXzZWZYH7oc06eo=s500

05-05 17:34:55.384: ERROR/NewsFeedAdapter(7101): Position- 4 Image- android.widget.ImageView@4613d058 Loading image- http://lh3.ggpht.com/iCKp7kwcnbnZGD4vBb-Mz_mtSKPvST-YGeekJ9khljpG-Ua5Kl71ETdn8LLulULmq9fgNy8huooi_CfrT4W3gjqoFhiB=s500
```

Comment: Can you add some insight to what is actually happening when the user hits the search key. Is that your class opening? What happens when a result is clicked, are you calling that same intent?

Comment: When the search key (hard key) is pressed, the [default interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) opens. When that happens, the user is presented with search bar, as well as some suggestions. As user types stuff in the suggestions update. When a suggestion is clicked, an intent is fired for NewsFeed class and the search activity is finished.

Comment: You should be sure to logout your lifecycle events, onstop, onstart, onpause, onresume. I'm thinking this is an issue of calling an activity (your results activity) while it is already open and are mixing up your old and new data.

Comment: I guess I will never find out. The problem resolved once I rearranged my layout a bit. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan`.